# "I thought he is/was a good boy." Which tense is correct?

Tags: past-tense

"I think he is a good boy". If I convert this to the past tense, which one mentioned below would be the answer ?

1. I thought he is a good boy.
2. I thought he was a good boy.

Kindly explain why they are right/wrong (for both the sentences) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reported speech (position of "was" in sentence)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73603/reported-speech-position-of-was-in-sentence) Saying *what you **thought*** is the same as when you're referring to *what you **said***, in that it's normal for native speakers to "backshift" to ***he was*** even though it might be contextually obvious that he ***still is** a good boy*. But especially so if what you previously thought is now obviously ***wrong***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  OP (and others) may be aware of backshifting in reported speech but not with internal thoughts or feelings.  I feel like this is a separate question, or else the duplicate should be expanded.

Comment: @Andrew: Good point. I've cancelled my downvote, so I can't vote here any more, but after looking at it more carefully (along with [tense in a sub-clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102108/), which covers similar ground), I think I'd rather close both of those in favour of your answer here! I don't see why we should always favour the *older* of "duplicates", and yours already seems like by far the best answer. Maybe a bit more about *reported speech*, but that's pretty easy (and you have actually *mentioned* it as the more common context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Was**.

This is called [*backshifting*](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm) and is most often used with [indirect reported speech](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm).  However it's also something English speakers do when talking about internal thoughts, emotions, or unspoken conversations (*think, feel, guess, reason, know, theorize, intend, plan,* etc.)

> He thinks I am crazy -> He thought I **was** crazy.

This of course raises the question whether he *still* thinks I am crazy.  The past tense implies that he has since changed his mind -- but the truth is, we don't know.  We can sometimes guess from context, or we have to ask the speaker for clarification.

In the same way, when we back-shift we sometimes change the meaning of the sentence.  We say what we thought *then*, but might not think *now*:

> I think it's a good idea to go to the beach today.
>   I **thought it was** a good idea to go to the beach today (but now it's raining, so I guess I was wrong).
>
> I think it would be a good idea to go to the beach today
>   I **thought it would have been** a good idea to go to the beach today (but then my son got sick and we couldn't go).

But not always.  Sometimes we're just talking about an internal thought that happened in the past, and is still true:

> I guess that Darth Vader is Luke's father.
>   I **guessed** that Darth Vader **was** Luke's father.

Exception:  If you relate your past thought to a current condition, you can use the present tense to indicate it's still true today.

> Since I was a child I knew that I **can't stand** broccoli.
>   Since I was a child I knew that I **couldn't stand** broccoli.

It may still *sound* better to use the past tense, but the present isn't wrong.

Comment: In some contexts one might actually *prefer* the non-backshifted version, because it carries stronger associations of "relevance to current time of utterance". So *He said I'm crazy* might be more suitable than *He said I was crazy* if the speaker is still particularly concerned about having been thus characterised (and either wants his audience to reassure him he's *not* crazy, or is "challenging" them to repeat the claim).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation but may I ask a question about your response? You mentioned that the sentence 'I think it would be a good idea to go to the beach today' can be back-shift to 'I thought it would have been a good idea to go to the beach today ' to indicate that looking back, you don't think it is a right idea. But can I still say 'I thought it **would** be a good idea to go to the beach today' to just indicate what I thought in the past rather than conveying any potential current disagreement?